# How to fix a Traceback problem in Dataframe Python on Ubuntu

Tags: python, dataframe

I tried to use DataFrame in Python. Commands are:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import uniform
df = pd.DataFrame(uniform(0,1,(3,4)),
                  index = 'A B C D'.split(),
                  columns='E F G H'.split())
```

But unfortunately I get the following error. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this issue?

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)
>   ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)    1680 
>   -> 1681         mgr = BlockManager(blocks, axes)    1682         mgr._consolidate_inplace()
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in **init**(self, blocks, axes, do_integrity_check)
>       142         if do_integrity_check:
>   --> 143             self._verify_integrity()
>       144
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in _verify_integrity(self)
>       344             if block._verify_integrity and block.shape[1:] != mgr_shape[1:]:
>   --> 345                 construction_error(tot_items, block.shape[1:], self.axes)
>       346         if len(self.items) != tot_items:
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)    1718
>   raise ValueError(
>   -> 1719         "Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed, implied)    1720     )
>
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 4), indices imply (4, 4)
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>         1 df = pd.DataFrame(uniform(0,1,(5,4)),
>         2                   index = 'A B C D'.split(),
>   ----> 3                   columns='W X Y Z'.split())
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in
>   **init**(self, data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
>       438                 mgr = init_dict({data.name: data}, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>       439             else:
>   --> 440                 mgr = init_ndarray(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype, copy=copy)
>       441 
>       442         # For data is list-like, or Iterable (will consume into list)
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/construction.py
>   in init_ndarray(values, index, columns, dtype, copy)
>       211         block_values = [values]
>       212 
>   --> 213     return create_block_manager_from_blocks(block_values, [columns, index])
>       214 
>       215
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in create_block_manager_from_blocks(blocks, axes)    1686
>   blocks = [getattr(b, "values", b) for b in blocks]    1687
>   tot_items = sum(b.shape[0] for b in blocks)
>   -> 1688         construction_error(tot_items, blocks[0].shape[1:], axes, e)    1689     1690
>
> ~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/internals/managers.py
>   in construction_error(tot_items, block_shape, axes, e)    1717
>   raise ValueError("Empty data passed with indices specified.")    1718 
>   raise ValueError(
>   -> 1719         "Shape of passed values is {0}, indices imply {1}".format(passed, implied)    1720     )    1721
>
> ValueError: Shape of passed values is (5, 4), indices imply (4, 4)

​

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating an 3x4 matrix but providing 4 row indices. Provide only 3 rows to  your `index`.

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import uniform
df = pd.DataFrame(uniform(0,1,(3,4)),
              index = 'A B C'.split(),
              columns='E F G H'.split())
```